# VS editorconfig putting each element of array on new line

Tags: c#, visual-studio

What setting in .editorconfig is breaking my array into new lines? I have auto cleanup on save enabled and I ran into a issue where I had a 256 byte array that the editor seems hellbent on breaking out into new line for each element.

Example, this:

```cs
    private static readonly byte[] _addonPublicKey = 
    [
        0xC3, 0x5B, 0x50, 0x84, 0xB9, 0x3E, 0x32, 0x42, 0x8C, 0xD0, 0xC7, 0x48, 0xFA, 0x0E, 0x5D, 0x54,
        0x5A, 0xA3, 0x0E, 0x14, 0xBA, 0x9E, 0x0D, 0xB9, 0x5D, 0x8B, 0xEE, 0xB6, 0x84, 0x93, 0x45, 0x75,
        0xFF, 0x31, 0xFE, 0x2F, 0x64, 0x3F, 0x3D, 0x6D, 0x07, 0xD9, 0x44, 0x9B, 0x40, 0x85, 0x59, 0x34,
        0x4E, 0x10, 0xE1, 0xE7, 0x43, 0x69, 0xEF, 0x7C, 0x16, 0xFC, 0xB4, 0xED, 0x1B, 0x95, 0x28, 0xA8,
        0x23, 0x76, 0x51, 0x31, 0x57, 0x30, 0x2B, 0x79, 0x08, 0x50, 0x10, 0x1C, 0x4A, 0x1A, 0x2C, 0xC8,
        0x8B, 0x8F, 0x05, 0x2D, 0x22, 0x3D, 0xDB, 0x5A, 0x24, 0x7A, 0x0F, 0x13, 0x50, 0x37, 0x8F, 0x5A,
        0xCC, 0x9E, 0x04, 0x44, 0x0E, 0x87, 0x01, 0xD4, 0xA3, 0x15, 0x94, 0x16, 0x34, 0xC6, 0xC2, 0xC3,
        0xFB, 0x49, 0xFE, 0xE1, 0xF9, 0xDA, 0x8C, 0x50, 0x3C, 0xBE, 0x2C, 0xBB, 0x57, 0xED, 0x46, 0xB9,
        0xAD, 0x8B, 0xC6, 0xDF, 0x0E, 0xD6, 0x0F, 0xBE, 0x80, 0xB3, 0x8B, 0x1E, 0x77, 0xCF, 0xAD, 0x22,
        0xCF, 0xB7, 0x4B, 0xCF, 0xFB, 0xF0, 0x6B, 0x11, 0x45, 0x2D, 0x7A, 0x81, 0x18, 0xF2, 0x92, 0x7E,
        0x98, 0x56, 0x5D, 0x5E, 0x69, 0x72, 0x0A, 0x0D, 0x03, 0x0A, 0x85, 0xA2, 0x85, 0x9C, 0xCB, 0xFB,
        0x56, 0x6E, 0x8F, 0x44, 0xBB, 0x8F, 0x02, 0x22, 0x68, 0x63, 0x97, 0xBC, 0x85, 0xBA, 0xA8, 0xF7,
        0xB5, 0x40, 0x68, 0x3C, 0x77, 0x86, 0x6F, 0x4B, 0xD7, 0x88, 0xCA, 0x8A, 0xD7, 0xCE, 0x36, 0xF0,
        0x45, 0x6E, 0xD5, 0x64, 0x79, 0x0F, 0x17, 0xFC, 0x64, 0xDD, 0x10, 0x6F, 0xF3, 0xF5, 0xE0, 0xA6,
        0xC3, 0xFB, 0x1B, 0x8C, 0x29, 0xEF, 0x8E, 0xE5, 0x34, 0xCB, 0xD1, 0x2A, 0xCE, 0x79, 0xC3, 0x9A,
        0x0D, 0x36, 0xEA, 0x01, 0xE0, 0xAA, 0x91, 0x20, 0x54, 0xF0, 0x72, 0xD8, 0x1E, 0xC7, 0x89, 0xD2
    ];
```

Turns into this after code cleanup:

```cs
    private static readonly byte[] _addonPublicKey =
    [
        0xC3,
        0x5B,
        0x50,
        0x84,
        0xB9,
        0x3E,
        0x32,
        0x42,
        0x8C,
        0xD0,
        0xC7,
        0x48,
        0xFA,
        0x0E,
        0x5D,
        0x54,
        .....
```

This makes the initialization of the array over 200 lines. My cleanup only uses my editorconfig settings. Note: If I remove "Fix all warnings and errors set in EditorConfig" the problem goes away but still cant identify the setting that is causing it. EdiorConfig for reference: https://gist.github.com/JBurlison/5499a369c26d9e67408974f67e7248c8

I have tried

```
csharp_preserve_single_line_blocks = true
csharp_preserve_single_line_statements = true
```

[image]

Comment: This is valid for c# 8, https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/collection-expressions

Comment: ...OK it's [a c#12 feature](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/proposals/csharp-12.0/collection-expressions) not 8, perhaps the new analyzer has a new configuration item.

Comment: Hi, I tried to use your EditorConfig configuration but the code you provided did not appear to have many lines. But here I have an idea, if you can't control it, you can add "#pragma warning disable format" and "#pragma warning disable format" before and after it. This prevents the pointed code from being formatted

Comment: Thanks for the work around that worked!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because JBurlison said the method I provided works, I decided to post it as an Answer.

I have tried using JBurlison's EditorConfig configuration and code, and formatted the code, but this code has not changed. Because this code is uncontrollable in JBurlison, and the EditorConfig does not seem to have been updated accordingly for C#12, the uncontrollable code can be excluded from the formatted code target, like this:

```
    #pragma warning disable format
    private static readonly byte[] _addonPublicKey =
[
    0xC3, 0x5B, 0x50, 0x84, 0xB9, 0x3E, 0x32, 0x42, 0x8C, 0xD0, 0xC7, 0x48, 0xFA, 0x0E, 0x5D, 0x54,
    0xC3, 0x5B, 0x50, 0x84, 0xB9, 0x3E, 0x32, 0x42, 0x8C, 0xD0, 0xC7, 0x48, 0xFA, 0x0E, 0x5D, 0x54,
    0x5A, 0xA3, 0x0E, 0x14, 0xBA, 0x9E, 0x0D, 0xB9, 0x5D, 0x8B, 0xEE, 0xB6, 0x84, 0x93, 0x45, 0x75,
    0xFF, 0x31, 0xFE, 0x2F, 0x64, 0x3F, 0x3D, 0x6D, 0x07, 0xD9, 0x44, 0x9B, 0x40, 0x85, 0x59, 0x34,
    0x4E, 0x10, 0xE1, 0xE7, 0x43, 0x69, 0xEF, 0x7C, 0x16, 0xFC, 0xB4, 0xED, 0x1B, 0x95, 0x28, 0xA8,
    0x23, 0x76, 0x51, 0x31, 0x57, 0x30, 0x2B, 0x79, 0x08, 0x50, 0x10, 0x1C, 0x4A, 0x1A, 0x2C, 0xC8,
    0x8B, 0x8F, 0x05, 0x2D, 0x22, 0x3D, 0xDB, 0x5A, 0x24, 0x7A, 0x0F, 0x13, 0x50, 0x37, 0x8F, 0x5A,
    0xCC, 0x9E, 0x04, 0x44, 0x0E, 0x87, 0x01, 0xD4, 0xA3, 0x15, 0x94, 0x16, 0x34, 0xC6, 0xC2, 0xC3,
    0xFB, 0x49, 0xFE, 0xE1, 0xF9, 0xDA, 0x8C, 0x50, 0x3C, 0xBE, 0x2C, 0xBB, 0x57, 0xED, 0x46, 0xB9,
    0xAD, 0x8B, 0xC6, 0xDF, 0x0E, 0xD6, 0x0F, 0xBE, 0x80, 0xB3, 0x8B, 0x1E, 0x77, 0xCF, 0xAD, 0x22,
    0xCF, 0xB7, 0x4B, 0xCF, 0xFB, 0xF0, 0x6B, 0x11, 0x45, 0x2D, 0x7A, 0x81, 0x18, 0xF2, 0x92, 0x7E,
    0x98, 0x56, 0x5D, 0x5E, 0x69, 0x72, 0x0A, 0x0D, 0x03, 0x0A, 0x85, 0xA2, 0x85, 0x9C, 0xCB, 0xFB,
    0x56, 0x6E, 0x8F, 0x44, 0xBB, 0x8F, 0x02, 0x22, 0x68, 0x63, 0x97, 0xBC, 0x85, 0xBA, 0xA8, 0xF7,
    0xB5, 0x40, 0x68, 0x3C, 0x77, 0x86, 0x6F, 0x4B, 0xD7, 0x88, 0xCA, 0x8A, 0xD7, 0xCE, 0x36, 0xF0,
    0x45, 0x6E, 0xD5, 0x64, 0x79, 0x0F, 0x17, 0xFC, 0x64, 0xDD, 0x10, 0x6F, 0xF3, 0xF5, 0xE0, 0xA6,
    0xC3, 0xFB, 0x1B, 0x8C, 0x29, 0xEF, 0x8E, 0xE5, 0x34, 0xCB, 0xD1, 0x2A, 0xCE, 0x79, 0xC3, 0x9A,
    0x0D, 0x36, 0xEA, 0x01, 0xE0, 0xAA, 0x91, 0x20, 0x54, 0xF0, 0x72, 0xD8, 0x1E, 0xC7, 0x89, 0xD2
];

    #pragma warning disable format
```